# TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'Response' with Python 3.4

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

**I'm getting this error and I can't figure out what the problem is:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/Scripts/ddg.py", line 8, in <module>
    data = json.loads(r)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'Response'
```

**This is my code:**

```
import requests, json

search_q = input('Enter query: ')

r = requests.get('https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=%s&format=json&pretty=1' % search_q)

if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    data = json.loads(r)
    node = data['RelatedTopics']['Result']
    print (str(node))
else:
    bad_r.raise_for_status()
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No need to load the JSON manually; the response has a `json` method.

```
data = r.json()
```

Comment: Thanks but then I get: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: Then you are using the data wrongly; probably `RelatedTopics` is a list, not a dict.

Comment: If i wanted to check the returned data is json or not?

Comment: You are the saviour

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `json.loads(r)` and `r` is not a `str` so `json.loads()` doesn't know what to do with it.

In the general case, you need to pass a string which contains valid JSON to `json.loads()`; though often, if what you already have is a Python object of some sort, it will usually contains attributes (or methods to extract attributes from its internal representation) which you can handle from Python, and so converting it to JSON so you can convert it to a Python object doesn't make sense.