# JSON object must be str, not Response

Tags: python, json

I'm making a request to a URL that returns a JSON file,

```
response = requests.get(url)
response = json.loads(response)
```

And then, I am attempting to go through some of the data,

```
for documents in response["docs"]:
    # do something
```

Right now, the error I'm getting is

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'Response'
```

In order to avoid this, I tried,

```
response = requests.get(url).json()
```

But then, I can't traverse the response because I get the error:

```
KeyError: 'docs'
```

I'm new to Python and not fully aware of the best way to get JSON data and parse it. Suggestions?

Here is a sample of the data being received,

> {'status': 'OK', 'response': {'meta': {'time': 9, 'hits': 11, 'offset': 0}, 'docs': [{'type_of_material': 'News', 'pub_date': '2017-01-01T09:12:04+0000', 'document_type': 'article', '_id': '5868c7e995d0e03926078885', 'lead_paragraph': 'The country’s leader spoke proudly of the progress of its nuclear weapons and ballistic missile programs.', .....

Comment: Perhaps you want to see what is actual output of `requests.get(url).json()` is by printing it out?

Comment: Try to print `requests.get(url).json()` and read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-using-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'Response' with Python 3.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35291021/typeerror-the-json-object-must-be-str-not-response-with-python-3-4)

Comment: Are you sure the JSON has a `docs` key? Maybe you should post a sample of the data.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Added sampl

Comment: That's a Python list of dict(s), not a string of JSON.  And/or the key you should be looking at is ...`['response']['docs']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to feed the response object to `json.loads()`. You don't get a string there, you'd have to access the `.contents` or `.text` attribute instead:

```
response = requests.get(url)
# Python 3
response = json.loads(response.text)
# Python 2
response = json.loads(response.content)
```

However, that'd be doing more work than you need to; `requests` supports handling JSON directly, and there is no need to import the `json` module:

```
response = requests.get(url).json()
```

See the [*JSON Response Content* section](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) of the `requests` Quickstart documentation.

Once loaded, you can get the `doc` key in the *nested* dictionary keyed on `response`:

```
for documents in response['response']['docs']:
```

Comment: As I said, I've tried requests.get(url).json(), but then I don't understand how to traverse the response...

Comment: @HumanCyborgRelations That sounds like a problem of not understanding what the API returns, not a Python problem.

Comment: @HumanCyborgRelations: you have a nested dictionary, the outer mapping has a `response` key, and the dictionary that references contains a `docs` key.

Answer (score 0):

`requests.get` returns a response object, which contains status information, headers etc. You need to access the raw document text from this object in order to parse the json or just use the provided json method:

```
response = requests.get(url).json()
```

(minus error checking)